# About android:displayOptions

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Please, explain to me the meaning of all options available in android:displayOptions
such as :

> -useLogo
>   -showHome
>   -homeAsUp
>   -showTitle
>   -showCustom 
>   -disableHome

I've read [Doc for Constant displayOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#displayOptions) but I still can't understand that

Comment: Please refer to [Doc for ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've read this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#displayOptions
But I still can't understand what's the meaning,

Comment: OK but my referred `URL` will give required explaination

Answer (score 10):

> #### useLogo:
>
> Use logo instead of icon if available. This flag will cause appropriate navigation modes to use a wider logo in place of the standard icon.
>
> #### showHome:
>
> Show 'home' elements (logo and icon) in this action bar, leaving more space for other navigation elements.
>
> #### homeAsUp:
>
> Display the 'home' element such that it appears as an 'up' affordance. e.g. show an arrow to the left indicating the action that will be taken. Set this flag if selecting the 'home' button in the action bar to return up by a single level in your UI rather than back to the top level or front page. Remember, that you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName attribute in the  element.
>
> #### showTitle:
>
> Show the activity title and subtitle, if present.
>
> #### showCustom:
>
> Show the custom view if one has been set.
>
> #### disableHome:
>
> haven't found this one, but there's a function setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean) in ActionBar class which can help to enable or disable home button.

All these can be found at [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) reference.